# Where is the the color scheme for Netbeans located in windows (which directory/file)?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Where is the the color scheme for `Netbeans` located in windows (which directory/file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7/8 color schemes are located in

- **/%appdata%/Netbeans/(version)/config/Editors/FontColors**

where (version) is your version of NetBeans, mine is 8.0 so in my case:

- **/%appdata%/Netbeans/8.0/config/Editors/FontColors**